# PHP IF( (X) || (X && Y)) Statement

Tags: php, if-statement

Can I have a number of conditions in my if statement

```
if( (X) || (X && Y)){
    echo "some statement";
}
```

And if I can, can it be written

```
if(empty(x) || !empty(x) && y==25)){
    echo "this is true";
}
```

Comment: Why not test it might be faster than asking here?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: P.S. You have an extra `)` in your 2nd example.

Comment: `if(empty(x) || !empty(x) ...)` is pointless. If `!empty(x)` will only be evaluated if `empty(x)` evaluates to false. You'd just use `if (empty(x) || y == 25)`.

Comment: `empty()` is a moronically stupid function to be using on numbers anyways. if `x` can be zero, then your logic will break. `empty(0)` is TRUE.

Comment: Your 2 examples aren't even the same.  What *exactly* are you trying to ask here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can have as many conditions as you want, however it is recommended that you structure them with parenthesis the same way we did in college when we were doing math.

```
if($a==1 && $b==2)

if($a== 1 && ( $b==2 || $c==3))

if(($a==1 || $b==2) && ($c==3 || $d==4))

if((($a==1 || $b==2) && $c==3) && ($d==4 || ($e==5 && $f==^)))
```

You can do as many levels as you want, but put parenthesis so you will understand how the conditions work.